# How to populate a Backbone model from multiple URLs

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

I would like to use a single Backbone Model that is composed of data from different URL endpoints. Is it possible to specify multiple URLs within a single model? I'd like to avoid calling AJAX by hand.

Until now, I've been using [jQuery Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to call multiple URLs and synthesize their results into a single object.

I can think of two options so far: building a Backbone model with a partial model for each URL, or using one URL and then overriding `Model.fetch()` to call the other URLs. But neither one makes me comfortable.

(Or I can try to bribe the API developer to provide a merged URL endpoint...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think both of the ways you suggested are quite reasonable, but personally I'd vote for the `fetch` approach.

Using nested models has the advantage of working "out of the box"; in other words, by using one model for every server <=> client mapping you avoid having to change any `Backbone.Model` methods.  The problem with this approach though is that you wind up with a conglomeration of multiple models.

If that makes sense anyway (data retrieval aside) then stick to nested models.  But if not you're forcing the rest of your code to work with several models instead of just one solely to keep your data retrieval code simple.  If you'd rather just complicate the data retrieval code and keep everything else simple then you're better off overwriting `fetch`.

`fetch` does one thing, and that is retrieve data via a one-to-one mapping between it and a remote URL.  If you want a one-to-**many** mapping instead it makes perfect sense to just override the default `fetch` behavior.  Plus you know it's reasonably safe to override `fetch` because it's name isn't `_fetch`, and Backbone uses the the underscore style to name it's pseudo-private methods (eg. `_validate`).

If you still don't like either of those approaches, there is one other option: `request` events.  The latest version of Backbone has a new event called `request` that is triggered whenever a `fetch` is started.  What this means is that you can setup an event handler that retrieves your secondary data in response to the primary data's request, like so:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('request', this.handleRequest);
        _.bindAll(this, 'handleTriggeredResponse');
    },
    handleRequest: function() {
        $.ajax({url: secondDataUrl, complete: this.handleTriggeredResponse});
        $.ajax({url: tertiaryDataUrl, complete: this.handleTriggeredResponse});
    },
    handleTriggeredResponse: function(response) {
        this.set(response.data);
    },
    url: firstDataUrl
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit GammaGames: the `_(this)` style used to be perfectly viable, but I guess Underscore has since moved away from it, and the other fixes for my sloppiness were also appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

There is another solution. To override default Backbone.ajax function with advanced jquery ajax execution that supports array or hash of urls. It will load data in parallel and pass control back to Backbone model once all requests are completed.

```
ajaxForArray = ->
  options = _.first arguments
  $.when.apply $, options.url.map (url) ->
    $.ajax _.merge _.omit(options, ['url', 'success']), {url}
  .done ->
    resp =
      if options.url.length > 1
        _.slice(arguments).map (arg) -> _.first arg
      else
        _.first arguments
    options.success? resp

ajaxForHash = ->
  options = _.first arguments
  pairs = _.transform options.url, (memo, url, key) ->
    memo.push {key, url}
  , []
  $.when.apply $, pairs.map (pair) ->
    $.ajax _.merge _.omit(options, ['url', 'success']), url: pair.url
  .done ->
    resp = _.slice(arguments).reduce (memo, arg, i) ->
      memo[pairs[i].key] = _.first arg
      memo
    , {}
    options.success? resp

Backbone.ajax = ->
  options = _.first arguments
  if _.isArray options.url
    ajaxForArray.apply $, arguments
  else if _.isObject(options.url) and not _.isFunction options.url
    ajaxForHash.apply $, arguments
  else
    $.ajax.apply $, arguments
```

Now models could be set with array of urls, like

```
class ArrayBasedModel extends Backbone.Model
  url: ['/aoo', '/boo', '/coo']
  parse: (resp) ->
    super _.extend {}, resp[0], resp[1], resp[2]
```

or hash of urls, like

```
class HashBasedModel extends Backbone.Model
  url: {aoo: '/aoo', boo: '/boo', coo: '/coo'}
  parse: (resp) ->
    super _.extend {}, resp.aoo, resp.boo, resp.coo
```

so when parse() is overridden, just add some basic logic of merging results from all ajax calls to pass it down to Backbone.Model.parse().

After all this, the properties from different URLs will be available in one model attributes.