# How to build a Backbone model that can be used for several URLs?

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js

I'm building my first webapp with [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) in which I've got one model (which is a "Quote") that I can get from several sources from the API. For example, there is one call which get's the latest quote:

```
'/quote/latest'
```

and I've got one from which I get a random one:

```
'/quote/random'
```

and there are a couple more variations. So to get the first one going I first made this simple model:

```
var QuoteModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'quote/latest'
});
```

Do I now have to make one model for each URL? Or how do I make this QuoteModel dynamic? All tips are welcome!

Comment: This could perhaps help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472169/how-to-populate-a-backbone-model-from-multiple-urls

Answer (score 2):

urlRoot can be a function that returns the urlRoot you want. A quick example could be to override the fetch passing what you would like to fetch

```
var QuoteModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: function(){
      return "/quote/"+this.request
    },

  fetch:function(request){
    this.request = request;
    Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this);
  }
});


var quoteModel = new QuoteModel();

quoteModel.fetch("new");
```

[here is a code pen where you can see changing what is passed into you the overridden fetch is applied to the super fetch request](http://codepen.io/leighquince/pen/Ickzw)

Comment: You could also have separate `fetchLatest` and `fetchRandom` methods if you didn't want to override `fetch`, you'd just need to make sure there was a sensible default for `request`.